# ASP.NET MVC4 Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View model

```
public class TrainingProgramScheduledDateVM
  {

public bool IsTuesday { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string TueStartTime { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string TueEndTime { get; set; }

    public bool IsWednesday { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string WedStartTime { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string WedEndTime { get; set; }

    public bool IsThursday { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string ThuStartTime { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string ThuEndTime { get; set; }

  }
```

I want to put the validation i a way that.
1- If IsTuesday = true Then TueStartTime and TueEndTime should Requires.
and so on for other

2- At least one boolean value should be true and relevant time should be required.

please suggest me any easy way.

Thanks

Comment: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use remote validation. For example, [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

```
        [Remote(
        "doesProductNameExistUnderCategory", 
        "Northwind", 
        AdditionalFields = "Category_ID",
        ErrorMessage = "Product name already exists under the chosen category. Please enter a different product name.",
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    )]
    [Required]
    public string Product_Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: How is that going to help with posting and validating a new model?

Comment: Can you please send the proper example.

Comment: Complete sample here: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-remote-validation-for-multiple-fields-with-additionalfields-property

Comment: @CodeCaster: remote validation can help you to implement very sophisticated validation: by two, three fields. It also allows to validate data by additional data from database. This is not only way, but I like this approach.

Comment: sounds good. but not suits on my case, i dont want to be post back for just validation.

Comment: Its not full page post back: it makes background ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I see repetition. This block:

```
public bool IsTuesday { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public string TueStartTime { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public string TueEndTime { get; set; }
```

Can better be abstracted into its own type, like:

```
public class ScheduleDate
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [RequiredIf(IsSelected)]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [RequiredIf(IsSelected)]
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `TrainingProgramScheduledDateVM` can contain a list of `ScheduleDate` objects.

Comment: I think it will not make sense. can you please send the example ?

Comment: @SirajHussain I cannot send an example, you will have to implement this in your code.

Comment: In what assembly is defined RequiredIfAttribute? I can't find it.